# How to rotate Binary Tree recursion given a null stopper

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm reading Strings from a file and have recorded '~' whenever the child of a node is null. I am then taking those strings and adding them to a Binary Tree. BUT my code is simply adding all the Strings (inclusive of the '~') into left tree nodes.

How do i get the algorithm to stop adding left nodes when a '~' is reached and to insert a right node (unless of course the next String is also a '~') ?

Here's my code:

```
// Reads the elements in the tree in pre-order
public void fromFile()
{
   BufferedReader in;
   String s = null;
   try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("animal_game.txt"));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while( (s=in.readLine()) != null )
        {

            stringBuffer.append(s);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");

        }

        fromFile(stringBuffer.toString());


        in.close();
   } 
   catch (IOException ex) 
   {
           Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } 

}

public void fromFile(String s)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = new Node<>((T)s);
        size++;
    } 
    else 
    {
        fromFile(root, s);   
    }
}

// helper function
private void fromFile( Node<T> node, String s) 
{
        // if null tree node reached, 
        if(s==NULL_TREE_NODE)
        {
            fromFile(node, s);
        }

        // insert left node
        if (node.no == null) 
        {
            node.no = new Node<>((T)s);
        } 
        else 
        {
            fromFile(node.no, s);
        }

        // insert right node
        if (node.yes == null) 
        {
            node.yes = new Node<>((T)s);
        } 
        else{
            fromFile(node.yes, s);
        }
}
```

This is my code that saves the tree to a file:

```
// Writes the elements in the tree in pre-order
public void toFile()
{
    // Writes in preorder starting with the root node
    if (root != null) 
    {
        BufferedWriter out;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("animal_game.txt"));
            toFile(out, root);
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
}

// Helper function
private void toFile(BufferedWriter out, Node<T> node) 
{
    try {

        if (node == null) {
        out.write(NULL_TREE_NODE); // null
        out.newLine();
        return;
    }
    //assert !node.data.equals(NULL_TREE_NODE); // Reserver for us..
    out.write((String)node.data); // these nodes hold Strings
    out.newLine();
    toFile(out, node.no);
    toFile(out, node.yes);

    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

and this is my file

---

Is it a mammal?

Is it a reptile?

Is it a fish?

Pelican

~

~

Shark

~

~

Is it extinct?

Turtle

~

~

Velociraptor

~

~

Does it have fur?

Elephant

~

~

Cat

Comment: Could you give us the whole file? The overall goal of this process? Currently, it seems that fromFile(Node, String) will always terminate without actually adding any information to the nodes, unless s== NULL_TREE_NODE in which case it only calls itself resulting in stack overflow? Also, are you meaning to use == for String equality there?

Comment: this is a function in my Tree class. i call it in the main with treename.fromFile();

Comment: But this creates a tree with all left nodes inclusive of the '~' character

Comment: How would i go about calling it's parent in case of s==NULL_TREE_NODE?

Comment: I meant could you show us the whole Tree class. I think it is producing all left nodes because first it checks if node.no (left) is null. I still don't see how the string data ever gets into the tree.Is it a good idea to put all the objects in one String first? Might it make more sense to make a List<String> seperated by newlines? (You already have the information given by the reader). You shouldn't "call the parent" when a null tree node is reached, but rather return, as you were originally called from the parent if it is structured correctly.

Comment: I updated it with the method(s) that save the tree to a file.  I do have a newLine separator to distinguish between strings.

Comment: hmmm, how should i structure the method to simply have a return statement when a '~' is reached?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your fromFile() to match your toFile(): instead of accepting a Node and a String representing the whole file, take a BufferedReader, allowing it to easily read off individual lines. In addition, change the helper build function to return a Node so it can return null in case of a ~ node.
Then, the whole tree can be build recursively, returning null back up the tree when ~ nodes are reached:

```
 private Node<T> fromFile(BufferedReader s) throws IOException
    {

            String line = s.readLine();
            if(line == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("File does not specify complete tree");
            // if null tree node reached, 
            if(line.equals(NULL_TREE_NODE)) return null;
            Node<T> node = new Node<>();
            node.data = line;
            node.no = fromFile(s);
            node.yes = fromFile(s);
            return node;
    }
```

Then, slightly adjust your fromFile():

```
public void fromFile()
{
   try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("animal_game.txt"))) 
   {
        root = fromFile(in);
   } 
   catch (IOException ex) 
   {
           Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } 

}
```

I have also modified it to use a try-with-resources statement for ease, and guarantee of proper resource release on exception. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Hope this helps.